# Error en array con Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Tengo dos `arrays` los cuales contienen ciertos valores el primer `array` esta predefinido y el segundo `array` es igual al primer `array`. El segundo `array` en si es un `array` auxiliar el cual lo utilizo para eliminar elementos. El error que tengo es que cuando elimino elementos del segundo `array` también se borran los elementos del primer `array`, Este es mi código:

Al momento de verificar mi `array` esta vació. ¿Cómo puedo resolver este error? y aquí mi [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dimoreno/pbL1b5e6/)

```js
function Ctrl($scope) { 

  $scope.categorias = [{"id_categoria":2,"id_empresa":2},{"id_categoria":3,"id_empresa":2}];
  $scope.categorias_Aux = $scope.categorias;

  $scope.eliminar_categoria = function(id_categoria){
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.categorias_Aux.length; i++){
      if ($scope.categorias_Aux[i].id_categoria == id_categoria) { 
          $scope.categorias_Aux.splice(i, 1);
          break;
      }
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.categorias))

    }

  $scope.verificar = function(){
    $scope.categorias_Aux = $scope.categorias;
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.categorias_Aux))
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>id</th> 
        <th>accion</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="i in categorias_Aux">
        <td>nombre cat</td>
        <td>{{i.id_categoria}}</td> 
        <td><input type="button" value="x" ng-click="eliminar_categoria(i.id_categoria)"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" ng-click="verificar()">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te he cambiado algo el código para que sea mas visual.
Le he estado dando mil vueltas, y lo único que he encontrado es que en lugar de igualarlos con `=` tienes que usar `.copy()`. Ya que con el primero es como si se relacionases y con el segundo son dos elementos separados.
[Fuente](https://thinkster.io/egghead/angular-copy)

PD: para mas información sobre copy, he lanzado una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92518/diferencia-entre-copy-y-clone)

```js
angular.module('app', [])

    .controller('contactController', function ($scope) {
    
    $scope.categorias = [{"id_categoria":2,"id_empresa":2},{"id_categoria":3,"id_empresa":2}];
    $scope.categorias_aux = angular.copy($scope.categorias);

    $scope.delete = function (item) {
        console.log(item);
            var itemIndex;
            var confirmDelete = confirm("Realmente quieres elminar el elemento con id_categoria " + item.id_categoria + " ?");
            if (confirmDelete) {
                angular.forEach($scope.categorias_aux, function(contact, index) {
                    if(item.id === contact.id) {
                        itemIndex = index;
                    }
                });

                $scope.categorias_aux.splice(itemIndex, 1);
            }
    }
})
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="contactController">
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>CATEGORIAS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>id_categoria</th>
      <th>id_empresa</th> 
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="categoria in categorias">
      <td>{{categoria.id_categoria}}</td>
      <td>{{categoria.id_empresa}}</td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>CATEGORIAS_AUX</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>id_categoria</th>
      <th>id_empresa</th> 
      <th>accion</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="categoria_aux in categorias_aux">
      <td>{{categoria_aux.id_categoria}}</td>
      <td>{{categoria_aux.id_empresa}}</td> 
      <td><button ng-click="delete(categoria_aux)">remove</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: gracias @GDP excelente respuesta

Answer (score 3):

El problema que tienes, es que al hacer `$scope.categorias_Aux = $scope.categorias;` también se esta copiando la referencia en memoria de `$scope.categorias` a `$scope.categorias_Aux` de tal manera que lo que le hagas a uno, afectara a los dos.

Para clonar el array, deberías inicializar la el array `$scope.categorias_Aux = []` y después iterar sobre el array original e ir insertando o los datos.

O de manera mas optima, `$scope.categorias_Aux = $scope.categorias.slice(0);` también te copiara los datos, sin copiarte la referencia.

**[Diferencia entre Shallow copy(copia superficial) y Deep copy(Copia profunda)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92518/diferencia-entre-copy-y-extend/92521#92521)**

Comment: Si está usando Angular también se puede usar `angular.copy($scope.categorias);`