# Diferencia entre .copy() y .extend()

Tags: angularjs

He estado curioseando un poco, no estoy muy metido en este mundo. Y la duda me ha surgido respecto a la diferencia que hay entre `=` y `.copy()`.

He encontrado un par de cosas en ingles, pero no he encontrado docu en castellano y me pareceria interesante tener referencias en SOE.

Por lo tanto, aqui os dejo la pregunta:

¿Cual es la diferencia entre `.copy()` y `.extend()` en AngularJs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalmente hay dos maneras de copiar objetos

**Copia superficial (Shallow copy)**

Utilizando el operador `=` se hace una copia de este tipo, estas copias hacen una replica del mismo objeto, copiando incluso la referencia en memoria, de tal manera ambas variables compartirán atributos y todo lo que le modifiques a uno, afectara a los dos.

**Copia profunda (Deep copy)**

Con el método `copy()` de angular o sobrescribiendo el método `clone()`en java correctamente o en cualquier lenguaje, se realiza una replica del mismo objeto pero se le genera un nuevo puntero de memoria de tal manera que tienen la mismas estructura e información, pero al tener distintos punteros, los cambios son independientes de cada uno.

**UPDATE**

**.copy()**

Realiza una deep copy de un objeto, manteniendo la estructura y el formato del objeto, pero creando un nuevo puntero.

**.extend()**

Nos permite extender un objeto, es decir, crear un objeto en base a otro/s u añadir mas objetos a uno ya existente.

Imaginemos que queremos añadir ciertos métodos y variables al $scope, haríamos por ejemplo:

```
$scope.thingOne = ‘one’;
$scope.thingTwo = ‘two’;
$scope.getThings = function() { 
    return $scope.thingOne + ‘ ‘ + $scope.thingTwo; 
};
```

Esto mismo se podría hacer con el método `extends()`:

```
angular.extend($scope, {
        thingOne: ‘one’,
        thingTwo: ‘two’,
        getThings: function() { 
            return $scope.thingOne + ‘ ‘ + $scope.thingTwo; 
        }
    });
```

Estamos extendiendo el objeto $scope añadiéndole los objetos arriba descritos.

**Nota:** Si te fijas en la propia [documentación de angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend), hay un apunte que dice

> Note: Keep in mind that angular.extend does not support recursive merge (deep copy). Use angular.merge for this.

Que quiere decir que no hace unión recursiva de los objetos, por lo que si los objetos con los que quieres extender tienen a su vez otros objetos, no se crea puntero para cada uno de esos objetos, y por lo tanto ambos objetos compartirán las modificaciones (copia superficial).

Ejemplo:

```
//Arrays para extender
var array=['a','b','c'];
var array2=['d','e','f'];

//El objeto que sera enxtendido
var obj={}

//Extendemos obj, añadiendole los arrays
angular.extend(obj,{array,array2});

//Si eliminamos el primer elemento del array 
array.splice(0, 1);
//Y consultamos el array del objeto. 
//veremos que tambien se ha borrado el primer elemento
console.log(obj);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/br1oqsd1/1/)

Espero que sea de ayuda.

Comment: Perdon @hictus, estaba a otra cosa a la vez, en esta pregunta quería poner extend() en referencia a este post, pero muy buena respuesta. Si la puedes completar con el cambio perfecto. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827866/angularjs-copy-vs-extend